# Лаунчер postman

Tags: ubuntu, postman, launcher

Как создать лаунчер постмана для ubuntu 18.04+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 . Скачиваем [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)

2 . В директории `/home/<username>/.local/share/application` создаём лаунчер:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Postman
Icon=/home/<username>/distr/Postman-linux-x64-x.x.x/Postman/app/resources/app/assets/icon.png
Path=/home/<username>/distr/Postman-linux-x64-x.x.x/Postman/app/
Exec=/home/<username>/distr/Postman-linux-x64-x.x.x/Postman/app/Postman
StartupNotify=false
StartupWMClass=Postman
OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;
X-UnityGenerated=true
```

3 . Сохраняем